# Некорректная отправка сообщений через vk api на Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Возникла проблема с vk api. Написал тестовую программу, которая должна просто дублировать сообщения пользователя. Для отправки сообщения использовал метод messages.send(). Дело в том, что при отправке сообщения, программа вступает в бесконечный цикл, начиная просто спамить сообщениями, который писал пользователь. При чём, если сообщений было несколько, то они отсылаются по очереди в таком же бесконечном цикле.
(Код почти полностью скопирован из Интернета)

Код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

def write_mes(sender, message):
   authorize.method('messages.send', {'user_id': sender, 'random_id': get_random_id(), 'message': message})

token = "..."
authorize = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(authorize)

for event in longpoll.listen():
   if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.text:
      mes = event.text
      sender = event.user_id  
      write_mes(sender, mes)
      print(mes + " id" + str(sender))
```

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку, написанную мной, https://github.com/lxstvayne/vk_maria.

Answer (score 0):

Я не доверяю библиотечным методам в данном случае, но, думаю ошибка здесь в том, что вы не обновляете `ts` лонгпола.

```
def get_long_poll_server(self):
     return self.vk.method('messages.getLongPollServer')

def updates(self):
     server = self.get_long_poll_server()
     while True:
         data = json.loads(requests.get(
            'https://{server}?act=a_check&key={key}&ts={ts}&wait=25&mode=2&version=2'.format(
                    server=server['server'],
                    key=server['key'],
                    ts=server['ts'])).text)
         if data.get('failed'):
             ...
         server['ts'] = data['ts']  # IMPORTANT MOMENT
```

Что такое вообще `ts`?

`ts` есть `timestamp`. Если быть точным, то количество секунд прошедших с `01.01.1970`.
Когда вы делаете запрос на сервер ВК о получении событий через `LongPoll`, то посылаете с какого момента получать обновления.

И если не менять `ts` после каждой обработки, то вы будете получать новые события + события, которые произошли после этого самого `ts`.